# Code should not evaluate at non-integers, fail at too few integers

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review, scripting

I want this piece of code to sort a given list by odds first and evens last. This piece of code did the trick with the list I entered in:

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,x, \[Pi],-3.33}
OddsAndEvens = Flatten[{False, True} /. GroupBy[Sort@list,EvenQ],{1,2}];

Out[5]={-3.33, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, \[Pi], x, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
```

But in the output, it sorts -3.33 where I need it to not evaluate the whole list when it encounters this. It seems to leave Pi and x alone but it should not evaluate there either. I also need the code to fail when the list has too few integers. I'm new to mathematica, so I wanted to try a While loop like this:

```
While[OddsAndEvens = True, If[list < 3, Break[]];Print["Failed"]];
 If[list !=_Integers,Break[];HoldAll]
```

Comment: `alist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, x, \[Pi], -3.33}` and then: `Flatten[#, 1] &@GatherBy[alist, {OddQ, EvenQ}]`. You can make decisions afterwards.

Comment: Perhaps something like `f[list:{__Integer}/;Length[list]>3]:=SortBy[list, {EvenQ, Identity}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may define a function for this:

```
mysort[list_]:=
If[AllTrue[list, IntegerQ[#] &],(* First check if list is valid *)
SortBy[list, If[OddQ[#], 1, 2] &], (*sort valid list*)
Failed] (* return Failed if list not valid*)
```

we can test this:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, x, \[Pi], -3.33};
mysort[list]
(* Failed *)


list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
 mysort[list]
(* {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!
This gives me the general idea, even though I need the list to not evaluate at all when non-integers are present, and to fail when there are too few available. I think I can work it from here.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `Switch`, `Which`, or `If` to perform flow control within your function. Depending on how many logical tests you need to perform and the desired outcomes, that might be easier.

If you just have a couple of tests, and you want the function to not evaluate if it fails, I would try performing logical tests on the arguments to the function.

```
mysort[list_?(AllTrue[#, IntegerQ] \[And] Length[#] >= 3 &)] := 
 Flatten[GatherBy[Sort@list, EvenQ]]
```

We have a function called `mysort` that takes in an argument `list`. The question mark tells it to test that argument agains the logical conditions (`&` simply tells it to slot `list` in wherever you see a `#`). It checks first to make sure that every element is an integer and second that the length of the list is greater than or equal to 3. If either is false, it fails and returns the input. If both are true, it will sort the list, gather by odd first, even second, and then flatten the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[0];

list = RandomSample[Range @ 10]
```

{8, 1, 5, 9, 10, 2, 6, 4, 3, 7}

```
f[{a__?IntegerQ}] := Flatten @ GatherBy[Sort @ {a}, OddQ]

f[_] := $Failed

f @ list
```

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

```
f[Append[Pi] @ list]
```

$Failed

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[0];

list = RandomSample[Range@10]
```

---

Using `GroupBy`:

```
f[l_?VectorQ] := 
If[MatchQ[l, {__Integer}], Catenate@Reverse@GroupBy[l, OddQ, Sort], $Failed]

f@list

(*{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}*)

f@{Join @@ {list, Pi}}

(*$Failed*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
alist = RandomSample[Range@15];
blist = Append[alist, { x, π, -3.33}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
    
f[k_List] := If[
  Length@Cases[k, Except[_Integer]] > 0
  , $Failed
  , {Sequence @@ Sort@Cases[k, _?OddQ], 
   Sequence @@ Sort@Cases[k, _?EvenQ]}
  ]
    
f /@ {alist, blist}
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}, $Failed}